# Visual Basic: Saving, Naming, Loading

Tags: vba, textbox, save, load

So, I'm making a dice-rolling interface. It has several textboxes where the player inputs their numbers, and then they just need to hit a button to roll the dice. Thing is, I wanted to be able to save several profiles for different players, since each player will have different configurations.

The videos and tutorials I've found are all about saving from a textbox onto a dropdown menu, or saving on the interface itself, meaning it's 1 exe per profile.

I'm a rookie, so I'm afraid I'm not explaining myself too well, and my code is likely to cause a few heart-attacks ^^''

How can I make a Save As function, where the player can name the file, save the values of each textbox that matters, and then have it load up the correct values? I'm attaching an image of the interface. Everything is working properly, except for the Save and Load buttons

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3qn0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach it's to save texbox values in the workbook cells before you save ( another sheet or where you need to ), for example :

```
cells(row1, column1)= texboxval1.text
cells(row2, column1)= texboxval2.text
```

And so on...
Then, you can call the save method :

```
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add 
Do 
    fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename 
Loop Until fName <> False 
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=fName
```

You can add all this code to a button on click event or as you may need.

Hope it helps !

Comment: This one seems similar to an option using My.Settings 

I'll give it a shot, thanks!

Comment: No prob my friend, remember to mark answer as correct if it solved what you needed.